# sva event scheduling with $display/uvm_error

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

So I recall when an assertion triggers the data signals in the assertion are from just prior to the clock edge.

I'd like to put a helpful error message in my assertion to let the user know what went wrong, but by the time $display() happens the data has already changed.

As an example the below assertion will fail whenever data=0 when a ready/valid handshake occurs.  However the $display that is printed will show data=1 if there is coincidentally a rising edge of data when the assertion fired.

```
  default clocking CLK @(posedge clk);
  endclocking
  //Assertion triggers an error if data is not = 1 when new data is clocked into the DUT.
  POS_DATA: assert property ((ready & valid) |-> data) else $display("[%t] POS_DATA fail data:%d",$time,data);
```

Is there a better way to code this assertion?

Created an [EDAPlayground Example](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/byx7) and looks like all the simulators do the same thing, so seems like it's my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add `$sampled(data)`

```
POS_DATA: assert property ((ready & valid) |-> data) else $error(" POS_DATA fail data:%d",$sampled(data));
```

And you should be using `$error` instead of `$display`. You'll thank me later when you start running regressions and getting coverage reports.

Comment: Awesome thanks. I missed that one.  I'm actually using `uvm_error() but was trying to make the example easier to elaborate/run when fooling around on edaplayground